# Fail2Ban can't insert iptables rule

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

It seems my fail2ban can't ban a host:

```
2013-06-22 18:18:24,546 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -n -L INPUT | grep -q fail2ban-apache-noscript returned 100
2013-06-22 18:18:24,546 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  Invariant check failed. Trying to restore a sane environment
2013-06-22 18:18:24,869 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -D fail2ban-apache-noscript -s 185.13.228.98 -j DROP returned 100
```

when i manually use the command, iptables complains:

```
# iptables -D fail2ban-apache-noscript -s 185.13.228.98 -j DROP
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
```

Although it seems the chain do exists:

```
# iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 412 packets, 36051 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   93  7257 fail2ban-apache  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443 
    0     0 fail2ban-sasl  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 25,465 
    0     0 fail2ban-postfix  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 25,465 
  311 27844 fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 130 
   93  7257 fail2ban-apache-overflows  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443 
   93  7257 fail2ban-apache-multiport  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443 
  311 27844 fail2ban-ssh-ddos  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 130 
  406 35205 fail2ban-pam-generic  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   93  7257 fail2ban-apache-noscript  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 296 packets, 105K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   93  7257 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-apache-multiport (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   93  7257 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-apache-noscript (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   93  7257 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-apache-overflows (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   93  7257 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-pam-generic (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  406 35205 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-postfix (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-sasl (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  311 27844 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-ssh-ddos (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  311 27844 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

What is the problem?!

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice the configuration of the chain from which you are trying to delete rules:

```
Chain fail2ban-apache-noscript (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   93  7257 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

There are no rules in that chain to delete at all except the return everything unmatched rule.  So, the blocking fail2ban is trying to remove is already gone.

Most likely, you can ignore this, as the command's goal has already been achieved.  Since you have no active bans you may want to run `/etc/init.d/fail2ban force-reload` just to clean up its state.